# Site gone offline after aborted mysql restart

Tags: database

After trying new my.cnf, restarting  mysql took to long (apparently due to some incompatible commands in the experimental config) , so I restored to my original my.cnf and restarts mysql successfully. But now I see that the site has gone off line. I tried the 'desparate' solution, i.e. issued:

```
UPDATE variable SET value = 's:1:"0";' WHERE name= 'site_offline';
DELETE FROM cache WHERE cid = 'variables';
```

but had no effect. Then I changed my database admin credentials. then, to possibly counter a corrupted table, I tried to repaire the database (MyISAM enginge) using

```
mysqlcheck -uroot -pPASS --auto-repair --optimize --databases MYDB
```

I also rebuilt the file permissions on the server.

No cure either.

I'd seen before that the site went offline on whim, but now this seems to become persistent. really appreciate your help to overcome this nasty problem.

Comment: Are you able to connect to the database directly in MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your database is broken. Drupal can't work without a database, and will display site offline if it can't connect to the database. If you fix your database, (And the data is still intact) Drupal should work fine.

For questions about databases you should go to dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Sorry if I posed the question in wrong place. Actually I restored a healthy backup, but it did not solve the problem!

Comment: @hbp If the problem is the database itself, you will get more help from database experts, if the problem is within Drupal, this is a great place to ask.

Comment: Alright, actually it was a silly mistake. I forgot to change credentials in settings.php after doing so in the database. Thanks for your hints anyway.